# (Error: System.Format Exception has been thrown. "Input was not in correct format")

Tags: c#, error-handling

Application is running, I have two classes within the program but my second class keeps getting this error.

```
class SandwichBuild 
{
    private string sandwichname;
    private double ingred1, ingred2, ingred3, ingred4;

    public SandwichBuild(string input1, string input2, string input3, string input4, string input5)   //sets variables
    {
        sandwichname = input1;
        ingred1 = double.Parse(input2);
        ingred2 = double.Parse(input3);
        ingred3 = double.Parse(input4);
        ingred4 = double.Parse(input5);
    }

    public void PrintOutput()
    {
        WriteLine(sandwichname + " " + ingred1 + " " + ingred2 + " " + ingred3 + " " + ingred4);  //Output for users responses
    }
}
```

I need my application to display final responses

Comment: On which line did you get the error?

Comment: I received the error on line 7.

Comment: ingred1 = double.Parse(input2);

Comment: And what is it you are passing in `input2`?

Comment: What are you passing to the class constructor? What is `WriteLine()`?

Comment: @Jimi I believe that is Console.WriteLine but if you do a static using to Console you can just do WriteLine.

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey Possibly. It shouldn't be a guessing game, though. As is guessing  what the OP is instantiating this class with. Or that this is a Console app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is the exception that is thrown if you pass a string that is not a `double` to `double.Parse(...)`.

This code will throw that exception.

```
 var result = double.Parse("Not a double or even a number.");
```

So, you are passing a none valid string into your constructor.